# style is missing required attribute

Tags: html, css

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<title>some title</title>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
// some styles...
</style>

<body>
<style>
// some styles...
</style>
...

</body
</html>
```

Using [w3c validation service](https://validator.w3.org) I've got the error:

`Element style is missing required attribute`

What is missing ?

Comment: I don' get that error message. I get the message " Element style is missing required attribute scoped", which is pretty much self-explanatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that `<style>` is inside `body`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<title>some title</title>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
// some styles...
</style>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Or you can use  `scoped` attribute, which allows you to place `<style>` tags within the `<body>` elements, but cross-browser compatibility is still realy bad http://caniuse.com/#search=scoped

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<title>some title</title>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
// some styles...
</style>
<body>
<style type="text/css" scoped>
// some styles...
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: solved by removing `style` from `body`. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

I believe your tag should have type="text/css" attribute.

Comment: That was in HTML 4. This is an HTML 5 document.

Comment: @Quentin How could you say that its a HTML 5 doc?

Comment: @VVK - it isn't an HTML5 document. There's no such thing. It's an HTML document that's being validated to the HTML5 standard, because that's the default for documents that have the preamble `<!doctype html>`

Comment: @VVK — Because the Doctype it uses is the one defined in the HTML 5 recommendation and not the one defined in the HTML 4 recommendation.

Answer (score -2):

Check out the fixes.

`<link type="text/css" href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">`

`<style type="text/css">`

`</body>` //body not closed

Comment: The type attribute was made optional in HTML 5 (which this document is). The end tag for the body element has *always* been optional in HTML.

Comment: And you made these changes, and you ran the changed version through the validator, and the error message went away?